# Check if file exists before using require in NodeJs

Tags: javascript, node.js

currently I use a dynamic path for some files.

```
        let targetFile = require(`../files/${name}.js`);
        targetFile.run();
```

but what if this file does not exist? `require` will throw an error. I changed the code to

```
    const filePath = `../files/${name}.js`;

    if (!fs.existsSync(filePath)) {
        // file does not exist
    } else {
        let targetFile = require(filePath);
        targetFile.run();
    }
```

but now the code always runs into "not found". Do I have to setup the absolute path?

Comment: Please provide your folder structure as the path provided in the fs is relative to the root of your project whereas in the require its relative to the file in which you require.

Comment: You could just use _try...catch_ blocks